# Why does php show error for my SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

UPDATE: My mistake - I made a typo. Nevermind this question.

I'm using php to update a mysql database. The resultant query I'm using when i print it out on my webpage before executing is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO perch2_content_items
(itemOrder, regionID, pageID, itemRev, itemID, itemJSON, itemSearch ) 
SELECT MAX(itemOrder)+1, 105, 81, 11, 118, 'json', 'search' 
FROM perch2_content_items WHERE regionID=105
```

When I copy and paste this query directly into  the phpmyadmin SQL interface, it works fine. The table gets updated. 
However, when I try to execute it using my php code as follows, it throws an error.

```
$insertToPerch = "INSERT INTO perch2_content_items
(itemOrder, regionID, pageID, itemRev, itemID, itemJSON, itemSearch ) 
SELECT MAX(itemOrder)+1, $regionID, $pageID, 
$regionRev, $newItemID, 'json', 'search'
FROM perch2_content_items WHERE regionID=$regionID";
mysql_query(insertToPerch) or die(mysql_error());
```

The error I'm getting is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insertToPerch' at line 1

Can anybody help me figure out why it is failing.

Comment: This is a terrible technique for incrementing the ItemOrder column. Why not use an [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) here?

Comment: Please stop using plain text editors to write code. Any decent IDE like netBeans or PHPStorm will highlight your code syntax and provide hints/warnings about bad code. In this case, PHP itself will emit a notice about using an undefined constant - if you had display_errors enabled, you would have seen it. (In addition to that, `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). [Here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). )

Comment: Aww :( why the down vote. I only started using php mysql this week. I admit, i made a stupid mistake, but i'm trying to learn.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli, how could I use AUTO_INCREMENT here? The MAX(itemOrder) is based on the regionID.

Comment: @DCoder, thanks for the pointer. I will look at MySQLi.

Comment: @ZincX: Does the ItemOrder *really* need to be dependent on regionID? Do the values really need to be strictly sequential within a region (i.e., 1,2,3,4,...) or could a looser ordering, provided by auto_increment, still be acceptable (e.g., 1, 5, 11, 19,...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `mysql_query($insertToPerch)` without the `$` its just the string `'insertToPerch'`

Comment: Of course! Its funny when you are looking at code for ages what you miss. Thanks a million.